# How do I install Nitro (http://nitrotasks.com) on 15.04?

Tags: 15.04

On all previous versions I can install by either visiting Software Centre or apt-get but on 15.04 it cannot be found anymore.

Any input appreciated thanks.

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no packages currently available with any PPA for newer Ubuntu versions like 14.04 or 14.10 and later, however, the old version still might work fine. Download the Nitro Tasks `.deb` directly from here: [ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nitrotasks/nitrotasks_1.5.1_all.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nitrotasks/nitrotasks_1.5.1_all.deb)

You can install it with terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package
```

Or using `gdebi` installer `sudo apt-get install gdebi` and just open it with `gdebi`.

Comment: This is it, I spent hours on it and couldn't do it.

Thanks heaps man you are a life saver.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Is the app still under development???